# Why does the sonar scanner image not find the sonar-project.properties with podman?

Tags: podman

I'm trying to analyze source code using a docker image based on the official `sonarscanner-cli` image using `podman` (on a RHEL machine).

When I run

```
podman run --rm -v ".:/usr/src" sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:4.7
```

the output shows:

> INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
>
> INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE

If I execute `ls -l` before the `podman` command, I can see the `sonar-project.properties` file there.

If I check out the same directory on my windows machine and run

```
docker run -v "%CD%:/usr/src" sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:4.7
```

I get the following output as execpted

> INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
>
> INFO: Project root configuration file: /usr/src/sonar-project.properties

Why does podman not find the configuration file? Did I specify the "volume" wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By executing

```
podman run --rm -v ".:/usr/src" sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:4.7 /bin/bash -c "ls -l"
```

I found out that the source of this was a permission problem:

> total 0
>
> ls: can't open '.': Permission denied

Adding the `--privileged` switch to the call fixed the problem:

```
podman run --privileged --rm -v ".:/usr/src" sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:4.7
```